# Is my circuit breaker bad?

Tags: stove

My Hotpoint stove shut off the burners while cooking. The light for "burner on"  stayed lit, but the burner went cold. I tried to reset the circuit breaker, and shut it off. The circuit breaker stays in the middle, and wont do anything, even with the stove unplugged. I tried turning off the main breaker, and resetting the stove breaker with the stove unplugged. The circuit breaker won't reset. It does however, allow enough current to allow the timer to blink on and off, even in the reset position, where it is neither on, nor off.
Is my circuit breaker (a double), bad?

Comment: What make and model is your breaker panel? Can you post photos of the panel please, even?

Comment: Did you turn the breaker fully to the off position then on ? This is a breaker reset procedure. What brand of panel do you have? Some stoves have a 240 feed and a 120 feed this could be the reason or not having a double pole breaker. 2 single poles side by side with only one tripping. Federal pacific stab lock panels are known to have this fault also.